# Is there a function to calculate the p-value of the rasters with the Spearman method?

Tags: r, geospatial, correlation, raster, p-value

I can not succeed to calculate the p value for the Spearman correlation for a series of the few rasters. I created a code to make spearman correlation. It works, but if I want to show me p value, using cor.test (), I have a error.

A reproducible example using a raster with 6 layers to compute the correlation between the cells of layers 1,2,3 and 4,5,6.

```
library(raster)
set.seed(89)
z <- brick(nrow=10, ncol=10, nl=6)
values(z) <- runif(600)

### Spearman correlation 
r <- calc(z, fun=function(x) cor(x[1:3], x[4:6], method='spearman'))

### p-value -- here I have the error
r.pvalue <- calc(z, fun=function(x) cor.test(x[1:3], x[4:6], method='spearman'))
#Error in setValues(out, x) : 
#  values must be numeric, integer, logical or factor
```

Comment: Can you please edit you question and provide a *minimal, self-contained, reproducible example*?

Comment: Hi, Robert. A reproducible example was made.

Comment: Thank you, I further simplified it.

Answer (score 0):

The function used in `calc` must return a number (or numbers). `cor` returns a number, but `cor.test` does not.

```
cor(1:3, 3:1)
#[1] -1

x <- cor.test(1:3, 3:1)
class(x)
#[1] "htest"
x
#        Pearson's product-moment correlation
#
#data:  1:3 and 3:1
#t = -Inf, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
#alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
#sample estimates:
#cor 
# -1
```

So we need to extract the p value from the object returned by `cor.test`. If you look at `?cor.test` or inspect `str(x)` you can see that you can use

```
cor.test(1:3, 3:1)$p.value
#[1] 0
```

And thus you can do

```
r.pvalue <- calc(z, fun=function(x) cor.test(x[1:3], x[4:6], method='spearman')$p.value)
```